Azure pipeline Java 11 Tool Installer not preinstalled
I am using the following yaml for an Azure pipeline, but getting an error.  Even though that image has Java 11 installed.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Error:

##[error]Java 11 is not preinstalled on this agent

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x86'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
    


Could you please edit your question and paste the error message?

The error is in the question...##[error]Java 11 is not preinstalled on this agent

TL;DR Use x64 instead of x86 in the JavaToolInstaller@0 task.
More details
There are no x86 pre-installed JDKs in Microsoft hosted-agent windows-latest  (same as windows-2022 as of August 2024).
Sample pipeline:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64' # <-------------------------- replaced value
      jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

Output of the installer task when running the pipeline:
Starting: JavaToolInstaller
==============================================================================
Task         : Java tool installer
Description  : Acquire a specific version of Java from a user-supplied Azure blob or the tool cache and sets JAVA_HOME
Version      : 0.243.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer
==============================================================================
Use preinstalled JDK from C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\11.0.24-8\x64
JAVA_HOME is being set to: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\11.0.24-8\x64
JAVA_HOME_11_X64 is being set to: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\11.0.24-8\x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\11.0.24-8\x64\bin
Finishing: JavaToolInstaller

See the list of installed software in Microsoft-hosted build agents.

Duh!  Thank you for pointing that out!  All working now
